# Real life example of lossy medium

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic

I’m learning about electromagnetic fields in class and a real life example of lossy medium would be helpful.
I also don’t know how intrinsic impedance connect connects to lossy medium - probably because I don’t understand impedance.

Comment: Anything that isn't perfectly empty space.

Comment: I gave an example. It won't help you. You **need** to understand the basics; wave impedance is already a bit more advanced than what you need to understand. You need to make sure Maxwell's Equations are familiar to you, and that you understand the proof of why they allow the existence of propagating waves in a medium. Then, you will need to look at that propagation and understand the role of the *wave number*, and how it relates to lossyness..

Comment: Saltwater is a lossy medium.

Answer (score 3):

Any medium that has a non-infinite resistance is lossy. For example, water, iron, air, the interstellar medium with a few ions in it, or a dog's fur.

Comment: A 0 resistance medium is also lossy (although it doesn't allow waves to enter it, so maybe it's not a 'medium'.

Comment: a medium is any matter between A and B, and gives clues about message travelling thru it as Marshal Mcluen once summarized. "The medium is the message."

Answer (score 0):

**The term "Lossy medium" all depends on the context or area of science** and interest. It could be Sonar and VLF 20 kHz in water used by submarines or anything that absorbs energy after energy is applied to it like hitting a golf ball with a robotic club.

I discovered when I was young that bird feathers are great for thermal insulation, electrical isolation, and pushing air, but at microwave wavelengths can also make low-loss dielectric antennae. (Journal article in mid'70's)

For RF, this is how the US Military who [initiated documentation for many global standards](http://everyspec.com/MIL-STD/MIL-STD-2000-2999/MIL-STD-2196_24678/) still used today, but later adopted by organizations like IEEE then other unions.

**lossy medium:** *A medium in which a significant amount of the energy of a propagating electromagnetic wave is absorbed per unit distance travelled by the wave.*

**examples;** Microwave oven with food,  CATV cable TV, Fibre optic cables

There are many sources of loss in communication.  To succeed there must be some defined minimum threshold to achieve an acceptable error rate that must be exceeded by the difference between the transmit (Tx) and receive (Rx) levels and the losses in between.  Some losses are reflected, absorbed, scattered, radiated in other directions and nulled by multi-path phase cancellation (Rice losses).

Not all losses are absorbed.  e.g. ;

- antenna may radiate power in many directions (beamwidth) which is inverse to its centre gain relative to 360 deg.
- The impedance mismatch (f) accounts for reflections but the path relative resistance accounts for absorption losses with the current.

  - These are 2 of 4 scattering loss parameters for any 2 port model.
  - s21 is the term for forward (port 1 to 2) path loss in the medium.
  - This is a function wavelength hence frequency and best describes a lossy medium.

[Theory](https://www.sjsu.edu/people/raymond.kwok/docs/ee140/Lossy_Medium.pdf) and [wider sciences](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/lossy-media)

**Discrete  component loss medium is measured in resistance**

Resistors [Ohms]   Max Power level is usually 100'C rise or 125'C should be derated to avoid high temp.
Insulators [ Mohms or Gohms]  This also depends on voltage << breakdown voltage.
Capacitors[ % Dissipation Factor for line f, ESR for high f]
Inductors [ Ohms at DC or DCR]
Enh-FETs  [ RdsOn at Vgs >> Vt]
BJT switches [Rce = Vce(sat)/Ic ]  This inverse with Pmax rating